# string index out of range - index error

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

# regular expressions

pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]*",
                 re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)

# Read pairs as lines of input from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:

    # loop through every word that matches the pattern
    for word in pattern.findall(line):
        while i < 1:
            if len(converted_word) != WINDOW:
                # print "word =", word
                if a_to_f_pattern.match(word[i]):
                   .....

            else:
               .....
        i = 0
```

this line here

`if a_to_f_pattern.match(word[i]):`

gives me the error in title and i cannot figure out why

previously, i had `while i < len(word)` and it worked but now because i want to only check the first letter of each word it does not work.

any clues?

Comment: Is your pattern matching an empty string?

Comment: ah no it reads words from text files.

Comment: Add `print word` to your loop.

Comment: hold on, hmm it seems you are right, i thought my pattern only took letters.

Comment: `*` means zero or more of whatever matches the preceding expression, so it will match zero letters. Use `+` instead to match at least 1.

Comment: have you verified you aren't trying to index an empty string?  adding "and len(word) > 0" to the While statement would help guard against any empty strings but not stop you from your current work.

Comment: @trapspring cheers this came in handy as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `[a-zA-Z]*` will match an empty string, because `*` means "zero or more". Use `[a-zA-Z]+` instead to ensure that your words are at least one letter long.

Also, since you're using `re.IGNORECASE`, you don't need to put both uppercase and lowercase letters in the pattern. And there's no need for the `re.MULTILINE` option if the pattern doesn't contain `^` or `$`, and no need for `re.DOTALL` if there's no `.` in the pattern. So it should just be:

```
pattern = re.compile("[a-z]+", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: hmm just tried this but it gives me duplicate words?

Comment: If the input line has duplicate words, the regexp will return them.